# Is it possible to dynamically adjust the data cells of columns in order for them to appear on the same vertical line?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass

I have been working to solve this issue in CSS for quite some time now. I have a table with 3 columns which show departures, time and situational text in case of e.g a delay or cancellation.
However as you can see in the pictures the 3rd column never aligns properly due to the 2nd column having dynamic text. I have tried with lots of different CSS properties and nothing has helped so far. Could it be due to the margin-left and margin-right properties ?

[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od8ns.png)

**CSS**

```
.busStop .tilerow {
display: flex;
border-bottom: 2px solid var(--tavla-border-color);
padding: 1rem 0 0.75rem 0;

&__icon {
    min-width: 2rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

&__label {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0.25rem;

}

&__sublabel {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 72%;
    min-width: 5rem;
    white-space: nowrap;    
    
    &__cancellation {
        background-color: $colors-brand-white;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        height: 0.875rem;
        overflow: visible;
        width: 0.875rem;
    }

    &__situation {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        height: 1.25rem;
        margin-left: 72%;
        width: 0.875rem;
        
        }
    }
}
```

**index.ts**

export function TileRow({ label, icon, subLabel }: Props): JSX.Element {
return (

```
        <div className="tilerow">
            <div className="tilerow__icon">{icon}</div>
            <Heading3 className="tilerow__label">{label}</Heading3>
            <div className="tilerow__sublabel">
            {subLabel.time}
            <SubLabelIcon subLabel={subLabel} /> 
            </div>
        </div>
)
```

}

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the 3rd column (*Avgang*) to always be the same width, whatever its content is. Is that it ?

Comment: Exactly, the 3rd column should not move anything by keeping everything in the same vertical and horizontal position. However in my case, if the texts on the 2nd column are not the same, the 3rd column gets affected. E.g you see in the picture where it says "Nå", the text in the 3rd column moves a bit to the left along with the warning symbol.

Comment: I didn't count the column correctly (I thought the column with 'Nå' was teh 3rd one) But I think I've answered your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `display: flex` on `.tilerow` all rows are independent, hence the difference in width in the 3rd column (*Avgang*).

`display: grid` on `.busStop` (and no more `flex`) will be a better suit.

Here is a quick snippet which of course needs to be adapt to React

```css
.busStop {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto 1fr;
}

/* Because .tilerow__* aren't direct children of .busStop */
.tilerow {
  display: contents;
}

.tilerow__item {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.tilerow__label {
  font-size: 1rem
}
```

```html
<div class="busStop">
  <div class="tilerow">
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__icon">{icon}</div>
    <h3 class="tilerow__item tilerow__label">{label}</h3>
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__time">Nå</div>
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__sublabel">{subLabel}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tilerow">
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__icon">{icon}</div>
    <h3 class="tilerow__item tilerow__label">{label}</h3>
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__time">Nå</div>
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__sublabel">{subLabel}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tilerow">
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__icon">{icon}</div>
    <h3 class="tilerow__item tilerow__label">{label}</h3>
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__time">1 min</div>
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__sublabel">{subLabel}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tilerow">
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__icon">{icon}</div>
    <h3 class="tilerow__item tilerow__label">{label}</h3>
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__time">2 min</div>
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__sublabel">{subLabel}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tilerow">
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__icon">{icon}</div>
    <h3 class="tilerow__item tilerow__label">{label}</h3>
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__time">10 min</div>
    <div class="tilerow__item tilerow__sublabel">{subLabel}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Please note that is this case I think using `<table>` would not have been a bad idea.

Comment: I ended up using custom React table components which I modified to suit the desired design and it worked. Thanks for the suggestion!